# How do you fix this attribute firefox error for selenium using python3

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium for the first time, but I keep getting errors.

I have tried uninstalling firefox,  changing my path variable so firefox would be recognized but nothing seem to work.
Note: I have added paths with the semicolon but didnt delete anything

Heres some code:

```
  from selenium import webdriver


  driver=webdriver.FireFox()
```

The error for the above code:

```
AttributeError: module selenium.webdriver has no attribute Firefox
```

I even tried this after typing in: from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
It was suggested by one of the many sources and documentation i consulted.

Comment: How did you install selenium ?

Comment: I checked a bunch of sources and stackoverflow posts but none seem to fix the problem

Comment: pip install selenium

Comment: What is the name of your file? Is it `selenium.py`?

Comment: in the cmd i checked i have the latests version

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452908/9396051

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Firefox'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065231/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-firefox)

Comment: Can you follow this link https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Comment: i have just tried pip install -U selenium and it gave of the requirment already satisfied selenium in... and the path its in

Comment: I shouldve mentioned all the stuff i tried in the question I have read about gecko engine, installed some github docs, changed my path to the location of the file, and i still get the above error

Comment: Thanks for the documentation anyways it was kinda helpfull ill try more stuff out and post an answer

Comment: In the documentation, section 1.4 tells you to use thiss command in the cmd:

Comment: C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium

Comment: but that gives off an error: The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: as I said in my comment to previously accepted answer -  your original post was FireFox, both in code and in error message (everyone can see from the edits). And you even admitted it come from some tutorials you follow. It looks like different problem now and should be asked separately, not edit previous (answered) question. Your code snippet does not include any shebang nor you provide information on OS, how many python version installed you have, etc.

Comment: I see your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `driver=webdriver.Firefox()`, i.e. only one capital F.

here is the [sample usage from the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)

Comment: This was not the problem it runs on my cmd when you type in python and write the line of code but fails in shell or a  python program starting with a shebang run on the cmd

Comment: well, your original post was FireFox, both in code and in error message (everyone can see from the edits). And you even admitted it come from some tutorials you follow. It looks like different problem now and should be asked separately, not edit previous (answered) question